# Subdivided bibliography with pandoc

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, pandoc, markdown

I use pandoc-citeproc for formatting my text (written in markdown), because I need to use a specific CSL style for the references of my thesis. Everything works well. I precise that I've set Pandoc to export to PDF, with the xetex engine.

Now, I'd like to subdivide  my bibliography in two sections : academic literature for one part, and newpapers articles for the other part. To doing that, if I've well all understood, I have to use biblatex to format bibliography... which is not compatible with CSL styles.

So, my question is simple : is there a way to subdivide a bibliography with pandoc-citeproc ?

Comment: The short answer is: no. Maybe you can write a filter. Your best shot is using biblatex and modifying an existing style to match the CSL

Comment: Ok. That's clear... I have to make a choice. Thanks ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but there is native solution for your issue: https://github.com/pandoc-ext/multibib

It let's you load multiple bibliographies in the yaml-header

```
---
bibliography:
  main: main-bibliography.bib
  software: software.bib
---
```

And print them wherever you want

```
# References

::: {#refs-main}
:::

# Software

::: {#refs-software}
:::
```